# WebApiConfig & what is the difference between routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApiController that implements two Get method: one that does not require a parameter and the other method requires an interger parameter...

```
//Get api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeVM> Get()
    {
        List<EmployeeVM> list = new List<EmployeeVM>()
        {
            new EmployeeVM(){
                FullName = "Milton Waddams"
            },
        new EmployeeVM(){
                FullName = "Andy Bernard"
            }
        };
        return list;
    }

    //Get api/<controller>
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

If I use the following configuration in my WebApiConfig class,

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

then I would get the following error:

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)'
>   in 'AngularForMVC.Controllers.EmployeeWebApiController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter."

Now if I use the this following configuration:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

then it works. I can execute the Get() method without any errors.

What is the difference? Why does the second code reference work? I know that I added an {action} into the url path, but even if I did not include the {action} path to the url this should still work.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of Application_Start in global.asax.cs? Make sure that Web API route registration is called before MVC route registration.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the id parameter as a nullable int. Get(int? id)

Comment: The nullable parameter won't help with the case of having two functions carrying the same Web Method

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using [Route] attribute to define my routes configurations than add new roles in route.config

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

A custom `[Route]` would be better for several reasons

1-Is to identify what each `GET` request is supposed to do. 
for example if you have `[Route("api/getlist")]` and `[Route("api/getitem/{id}")]` 
this would be more descriptive.

2-You won't face the problem you're facing now.